# How to limit Results in TestCase

Tags: javascript, rally, testcase

I want to take only 2 or 3 last results of TestCase. Is there an opportunity to limit and filter by date TestCaseResults in TestCase.

Right now I take results for each TestCase from TestCaseResult, but it makes too many requests to the server. I use sdk 2.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a query within your app, you could filter your TestCaseResults for a particular TestCase with a query such as the following:

`((TestCase.FormattedID = "TC6") AND (CreationDate > "2012-11-15"))`

You could dynamically adjust the date filter in your code to meet your criteria for how far back in time to grab results.